# Extracting and Printing text positions

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I've been doing some experiments on pdfbox and I'm currently stuck on a issue which I suspect has something to do with coordinate system.
I'm extending PDFTextStripper to get the X and Y of each character in a pdf page.
Originally I was creating an Image with ImageIO printing the text at the position I received, and putting a little mark (rectangles with different colors) on the bottom of each reference I wanted, and everything seemed well.
But now to avoid losing the style from the pdf I just wanted to overlay the pdf and adding the previously spoken marks, but the coordinates I got don't match in PDPageContentStream.
Any help on matching pdf coordinates I get from PDFTextStripper  -> processTextPosition to the visual coordinates

Using version 1.8.11

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: 1.8.11, any known issue? I can change version if needed

Comment: a quick change to the 2.0.0 RC3 doesn't seem to help, but I admit I didn't look for the alternative to the fillRect

Comment: I do have some code for 1.8 too, but if you don't insist on 1.8, download the 2.0 source code and get the DrawPrintTextLocations example, I think this comes close to what you want to do.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr (forgot to identify you and i'm not sure if it was needed)

Comment: damn it, i lost so much time and i've been using only the printtextlocations without noticing there is a drawprinttextlocations example

Comment: only ran it on the pdf and it seems to rightfully create box's on the characters, i'll work tomorrow adapting and trying to find out, what I did wrong.

Comment: The DrawPrintLocations example doesn't exist in 1.8. I have it on my computer but didn't commit it because it doesn't have all the features. When using the example, be aware that none of the two rectangles is an exact height. One is an heuristic height that is used for text extraction, the other is a bounding box that is often too high. If you need an exact bounding box, you'll have to get a glyph path and get the bounding box from that one. See in the user mailing list, this was discussed this or previous month.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103008/discussion-between-opetion-and-tilman-hausherr).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, this is the 1.8 version of the DrawPrintTextLocations tool that is part of the examples collections of the 2.0 version and which is based on the better known PrintTextLocations example. Unlike the 2.0 version, this one does not show the font bounding boxes, only the text extraction sizes, which is about the height of a small glyph (a, e, etc). It is used as an heuristic tool for text extraction. That is the cause for the "the textpositions i'm getting are halfed" effect here. If you need bounding boxes, better use 2.0 (which may be too big). To get exact sizes, you would have to calculate the path of each glyph and get the bounds of that one, again, you'd need the 2.0 version for that one.

```
public class DrawPrintTextLocations extends PDFTextStripper
{
    private BufferedImage image;
    private final String filename;
    static final int SCALE = 4;
    private Graphics2D g2d;
    private final PDDocument document;

    /**
     * Instantiate a new PDFTextStripper object.
     *
     * @param document
     * @param filename
     * @throws IOException If there is an error loading the properties.
     */
    public DrawPrintTextLocations(PDDocument document, String filename) throws IOException
    {
        this.document = document;
        this.filename = filename;
    }

    /**
     * This will print the documents data.
     *
     * @param args The command line arguments.
     *
     * @throws IOException If there is an error parsing the document.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        if (args.length != 1)
        {
            usage();
        }
        else
        {
            PDDocument document = null;
            try
            {
                document = PDDocument.load(new File(args[0]));

                DrawPrintTextLocations stripper = new DrawPrintTextLocations(document, args[0]);
                stripper.setSortByPosition(true);

                for (int page = 0; page < document.getNumberOfPages(); ++page)
                {
                    stripper.stripPage(page);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (document != null)
                {
                    document.close();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void stripPage(int page) throws IOException
    {
        PDPage pdPage = (PDPage) document.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages().get(page);
        image = pdPage.convertToImage(BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB, 72 * SCALE);
        PDRectangle cropBox = pdPage.getCropBox();

        g2d = image.createGraphics();
        g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(0.1f));
        g2d.scale(SCALE, SCALE);

        setStartPage(page + 1);
        setEndPage(page + 1);

        Writer dummy = new OutputStreamWriter(new ByteArrayOutputStream());
        writeText(document, dummy);

        // beads in green
        g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(0.4f));
        List<PDThreadBead> pageArticles = pdPage.getThreadBeads();
        for (PDThreadBead bead : pageArticles)
        {
            PDRectangle r = bead.getRectangle();
            GeneralPath p = transform(r, Matrix.getTranslatingInstance(-cropBox.getLowerLeftX(), cropBox.getLowerLeftY()));
            AffineTransform flip = new AffineTransform();
            flip.translate(0, pdPage.findCropBox().getHeight());
            flip.scale(1, -1);
            Shape s = flip.createTransformedShape(p);
            g2d.setColor(Color.green);
            g2d.draw(s);
        }

        g2d.dispose();

        String imageFilename = filename;
        int pt = imageFilename.lastIndexOf('.');
        imageFilename = imageFilename.substring(0, pt) + "-marked-" + (page + 1) + ".png";
        ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File(imageFilename));
    }

    /**
     * Override the default functionality of PDFTextStripper.
     */
    @Override
    protected void writeString(String string, List<TextPosition> textPositions) throws IOException
    {
        for (TextPosition text : textPositions)
        {
            System.out.println("String[" + text.getXDirAdj() + ","
                    + text.getYDirAdj() + " fs=" + text.getFontSize() + " xscale="
                    + text.getXScale() + " height=" + text.getHeightDir() + " space="
                    + text.getWidthOfSpace() + " width="
                    + text.getWidthDirAdj() + "]" + text.getCharacter());

            // in red:
            // show rectangles with the "height" (not a real height, but used for text extraction 
            // heuristics, it is 1/2 of the bounding box height and starts at y=0)
            Rectangle2D.Float rect = new Rectangle2D.Float(
                    text.getXDirAdj(),
                    (text.getYDirAdj() - text.getHeightDir()),
                    text.getWidthDirAdj(),
                    text.getHeightDir());
            g2d.setColor(Color.red);
            g2d.draw(rect);
        }
    }

    /**
     * This will print the usage for this document.
     */
    private static void usage()
    {
        System.err.println("Usage: java " + DrawPrintTextLocations.class.getName() + " <input-pdf>");
    }


    /**
     * Transforms the given point by this matrix.
     *
     * @param x x-coordinate
     * @param y y-coordinate
     */
    private Point2D.Float transformPoint(Matrix m, float x, float y)
    {
        float[][] values = m.getValues();
        float a = values[0][0];
        float b = values[0][1];
        float c = values[1][0];
        float d = values[1][1];
        float e = values[2][0];
        float f = values[2][2];
        return new Point2D.Float(x * a + y * c + e, x * b + y * d + f);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a path which represents this rectangle having been transformed by the given matrix.
     * Note that the resulting path need not be rectangular.
     */
    private GeneralPath transform(PDRectangle r, Matrix matrix)
    {
        float x1 = r.getLowerLeftX();
        float y1 = r.getLowerLeftY();
        float x2 = r.getUpperRightX();
        float y2 = r.getUpperRightY();

        Point2D.Float p0 = transformPoint(matrix, x1, y1);
        Point2D.Float p1 = transformPoint(matrix, x2, y1);
        Point2D.Float p2 = transformPoint(matrix, x2, y2);
        Point2D.Float p3 = transformPoint(matrix, x1, y2);

        GeneralPath path = new GeneralPath();
        path.moveTo((float) p0.getX(), (float) p0.getY());
        path.lineTo((float) p1.getX(), (float) p1.getY());
        path.lineTo((float) p2.getX(), (float) p2.getY());
        path.lineTo((float) p3.getX(), (float) p3.getY());
        path.closePath();
        return path;
    }

}
```