# Pdf to txt conversion

Tags: pdf, tabular, apache-tika

I have data in the form of pdfs and i want to convert it into text. I want to remove the images, header and footer, than the data will be left only in the form of multi-line tables, can you please suggest the best way to convert it? I tried tabula and apache tika but the results are not desired.

Comment: *"I tried tabula and apache tika but the results are not desired."* - You might want to instead ask a question to improve your tabula approach with code, link to example pdf, expected result, and observed result; and the same for your Tika approach. Your question now can be taken to be a recommendation request for some other library or service, and such requests strictly speaking are off-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

As you probably know, text in PDFs is arranged by x/y coordinates on the page.  Headers are not stored/identified as such, like they are in MSWord, HTML etc.

Good to hear that you’ve tried tabula:  https://github.com/tabulapdf/tabula . I’m sorry that it didn’t work for you.

If you’re working with journal articles, you might have luck with grobid https://wiki.apache.org/tika/GrobidJournalParser

To extract text by locations see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35299074

Answer (score 0):

http://pdftotext.com/
this works but probably not the way you where looking for

Comment: Thanks but this disturbs the format like hell. It won't work over here